# Why one torrent slow and others fast?

Tags: speed, bittorrent, utorrent

I've noticed that torrents with a lot of seeds are downloaded with the slow speed (10-50 Kb/s).
Why does it happen?

For example, I'm downloading 3 torrents with uTorrent 3.3:

1. Seeds: 17 of 168 (512 swarm). Peers: 9 of 3000 (771 in swarm). **Speed `10` Kb/s**
2. Seeds: 7 of 35 (0 in swarm). Peers: 28 of 517 (0 in swarm). **Speed 2 Mb/s**
3. Seeds: 37 of 83 (0 in swarm). Peers: 1 of 379 (0 in swarm). **Speed 2 Mb/s**

Answer (score 1):

Your download speed doesn't only depend on the number of seeds, but also on their speed. You could be lucky and have one that gives you 2 MB/s but it could also happen that you have 10 who only give you 1Kb/s each.

Comment: yes, it's not news for me; I know and I'm sure that the torrent with 10 kb/s has thousands of seeds.

Comment: but you are only connected to 17